# Downsides about using interface as parameter and return type in OOP

Tags: oop, interface, casting, parameter-passing, return-type

This is a question independent from languages.
Conceptually, it's good to code for interfaces(contracts) instead of specific implementations. I've got no problem understanding merits about the practice.

However, when I really code in that practice, the users of my classes, from time to time need to cast the interfaces for specific needs of specific functions provided by specific classes that implement that interface.

I understand there must be something wrong, either on my side or on the user's side, as the interface should expose all methods/properties(in the case of c#) that can possibly be necessary.

The code base is huge, and the users are clients.
It won't be particularly easy to make changes on either side.

That makes me wonder some downsides about using interface as parameter and return type.
Can people please list demerits of the practice? And please, include any solution if you know how to work around it.

Thanks a lot for enlightening me.

EDIT:
To be a bit more specific:
Assume we have a class called DbInfoExtractor. It has a public method GetInfo, as follows:

```
public IInformation GetInfo(IInfoParam);
```

where IInformation is an interface implemented by specific classes like VideoInfo, AudioInfo, TextInfo, etc; IInfoParam is an interface implemented by specific classes like VidoeInfoParam, AudioInfoParam, TextInfoParam, etc;

Apparently, depending on the specific object passed into the method GetInfo, the DbInfoExtractor needs to take different actions, as it is reasonable to assume that for different types of information, the extractor considers different sets of aspects(e.g. {size, title, date} for video, {title, author} for text information, etc) as search keys and search for relevant information in different ways.

Here, I see two options to go on:
1, using if ... else ... to decide what actually to take depending on the type of the parameter the GetInfo method receives. This is certainly bad, as avoiding this situation is one the very reasons we use polymorphism.

2, We should call IInfoParam.TakeAction(), and each specific implementation of IInfoParam has its own TakeAction() method to actually search and find the corresponding information from the database.
This options seems better, but still quite bad, as it shouldn't be the parameter that takes action searching and finding the information; it should be the responsibility of DbInfoExtractor.

So how can I delegate the TakeAction back to DbInfoExtractor? (I actually wrote some code to do this, but it's neither standard nor elegant. Basically I make parameter classes nested classes in DbInfoExtractor, so that they can call various versions of TakeAction of DbInfoExtractor.)

Please enlighten me!
Thanks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not

```
public IVideoInformation GetVideoInformation(VideoQuery);
public IAudioInformation GetAudioInformation(AudioQuery);
// etc.
```

It doesn't look like there's a need for polymorphism here.

The query types are [Query Objects](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html), if you need those. They probably don't need to be interfaces; they know nothing about the database. A simple list of parameters (maybe just ID) might be sufficient.

The question is what does the client have, and what do they want? That's your interface.

Switch statements and casting are a smell, and typically mean that you've violated the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).